# Data Access Layer - Switching from Local SQL Database to Cloud Data Storage

Tags: entity-framework, storage, cloud

I am creating a simple application and getting stuck with data storage option. To begin with I would like to use SQL Server as my data storage. I will not be using any special features of SQL Server, its pure tables with CRUD operations. 
Now I should be able to switch the underlying data store to either SQL Data Services or Amazon S3 by changing few configuration parameters.

Is this possible??? If yes, can anyone provide high level guidance on how to go about it? Do I need to use Entity Framework to begin with SQL Server? Does Entity Framework supports SQL Data Services? Any common component which supports both SQL Data Services and Amazon S3?

Too many questions!!!

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest ORM I know of is [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/lightspeed/comparison.aspx).  I've never used it though.  Personally, if the end goal is to use cloud storage, I'd probably just use cloud storage from the get go...

If you are going to use Amazon's SimpleDB, M/Gateway has a [open source db that mimics their API](http://gradvs1.mgateway.com/main/index.html?path=mdb).